# can we send the id to the file itself with submit form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I tried to post id to file itself in php. But it post nothing. This code I tried

```
//if can it should echo 1 and point 232
<?php 
   if ($_POST['submit'] == 'winners') {
     $a = $_GET['A'];
     echo $a;

     $point = $_GET['POIN'];
     echo $point;
   }
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" style="width:auto;">
    <div class="box">
        <span class='odometer' id="timespan" name="timespan">232</span>
    </div>
    <input class="process" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="winners" onclick="location.href='reward-pollingx.php?A=1&POIN='+document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML'">
</form>
```

Comment: question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to **GET** value inside **span** in PHP using JavaScript. Try something like this:

```
<?php

 $a = isset( $_GET['A'] ) ? $_GET['A'] : '';
 echo $a;
 $point = isset( $_GET['POIN'] ) ? $_GET['POIN'] : '';
 echo $point;

?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" style="width:auto;">

    <div class="box">
        <span class='odometer' id="timespan" name="timespan">232</span>
    </div>

    <input 
    class="process" 
    name="submit" 
    type="submit" 
    id="submit" 
    value="winners" 
    onclick="window.location='reward-pollingx.php?A=1&POIN='+document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML;return false;"
    >

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to pass parameters like a query string you do not need to use a form.

Because you configure your form to send a post request, you can pass the parameters of the query string to input values of hidden type. Test as follows

```
<form action="reward-pollingx.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" style="width:auto;">
    <input type="hidden" name="A" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="POIN" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="winners">

    <div class="box">
        <span class='odometer' id="timespan" name="timespan">232</span>
    </div>
    <input class="process" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="winners">
</form>

<script>
    document.querySelector('input[name=POIN]').value = document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML;
</script>
```

Your php code should change to use $_POST instead of $_GET

```
<?php

if ($_POST['submit'] === 'winners') {
    $a = $_POST['A'];
    echo $a;

    $point = $_POST['POIN'];
    echo $point;
}
```

Or use query string to pass parameters to the PHP script

```
<a href="reward-pollingx.php?submit=winners&A=1&POIN=...">Submit</a>
```

And the php

```
if ($_GET['submit'] === 'winners') {
    $a = $_GET['A'];
    echo $a;

    $point = $_GET['POIN'];
    echo $point;
}
```

To build the query string because you need to get information from the view you probably need to build it dynamically

Answer (score 1):

If you need to submit the form to itself, you can use

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" ....
```

or you can use:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="POST" ....
```